# In Mobile web Automation Iam unable to click on sing out icon present inside menu of Rediff mail site on Android mobile chrome browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

I am practicing by self on the mobile automation. I am trying to automate the rediffmail mobile site though i am able to login but then i am not able to click on the sign out icon or text which is present on the side menu as shown in the below figure.[image]

Please find the mobile code below that i am using

```
UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options()
                             .setPlatformName("Android")
                             .setDeviceName("2893f9bcf63f7ece")
                             .setChromedriverExecutableDir(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\")
                                                 .noReset().withBrowserName("Chrome");
                                                 
        androidDriver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(prop.getAppiumServerURL()), options);
        
        androidDriver.navigate().to("https://mail.rediff.com/cgi-bin/login.cgi?mobilelogin=1");
        
        appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='login']")).clear();
        appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='login']")).sendKeys("abc@rediffmail.com");
        appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='passwd']")).clear();
        appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='passwd']")).sendKeys("abc@rediffmail.com");
        
        appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value=' Sign in ']")).click();
        
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        
        appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='div_center_header']//span[@class='mobile_sprite topmenu']")).click();
        
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        
        //clicking on logout 
        //appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Sign Out')]")).click();
        
        appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='menu_signout']//em")).click();
```

After executing the above code I don`t see any errors or getting failed but actually no actions or click operation is performed sign out.

Can somebody please help me on this issue.